# I need to fix this code not completing to the end

Tags: python

```
def isMagicDate(day,month,year):
    if day* month == year %100:
        return True 
    return False
def magic():
    for year in range(1900,2000):
        for month in range(1,13):
            for day in range(1,month,year+1):
                if isMagicDate(day,month,year):
                    print("%02d/%02d/%04d is a magic date "%(day,month,year))
magic()
```

I need to fix this code he's not giving all magic dates in 1900 to 2000

Comment: Why do you have `for day in range(1,month,year+1)`? That's only going to give you day 1 (or no days at all in the first month).

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you done any debugging? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
def isMagicDate(day,month,year):
    if day* month == year %100:
        return True
    else:
        return False
def magic():
    for year in range(1900,2000):
        for month in range(1,13):
            for day in range(1,30):
                if isMagicDate(day,month,year):
                    print("%02d/%02d/%04d is a magic date "%(day,month,year))
magic()
```

TRY THIS!!
U have to put else after the if statement or the second statement will be excuted always,and also every month has 30 or 31 days(my code only take 30 days for every month).

Comment: You dont need to put else in the function, because if the first statements is True, then the whole functions returns that and ends there.

Answer (score 2):

Using [monthRange](https://techoverflow.net/2019/05/16/how-to-get-number-of-days-in-month-in-python/) to adjust for the different days by month (i.e. Feb vs. January)

```
from calendar import monthrange

def isMagicDate(day, month, year):
  return True if day*month == year % 100 else False

def main():
  for year in range(1900, 2000):
    for month in range(1, 13):
      for day in range(1, monthrange(year, month)[1] + 1):
        if isMagicDate(day, month, year):
          print(f"{day:02d}/{month:02d}/{year:04d} is magic date.")

main()
```